# c# iOS 10 Notifications - GetDictionaryOfValuesFromKeys() error

Tags: c#, ios, notifications, xamarin.ios

For iOS 9 and prior, I'm creating a dictionary of some notification data along with some user data and finally passing that data to the `UserInfo` property of the `UILocalNotification` while creating a local notification. 
In the `ReceivedLocalNotification` override, before I can handle the received notification, I check using `notification.UserInfo.ContainsKey()` to determine which type of notification it is and then handle it appropriately.

To cater for the new iOS 10 changes, I save the additional data by passing the values to the `UserInfo` property of the new `UNMutableNotificationContent`. The challenge happens when I try to retrieve this extra data in iOS 10.

I have implemented a `UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate` class and overriden the `DidReceiveNotificationResponse` function. Inside this function I have tried to access the extra data using the `GetDictionaryOfValuesFromKeys()` function, but the app crashes each time it hits that line.

Below is my code:

**The extra data I pass to the notification**

```
NSMutableDictionary userInfo = new NSMutableDictionary();
userInfo.Add((NSString)Constants.PushNotificationInfoKeys.NOTIFICATION_TYPE, (NSNumber)((int)Constants.PushNotificationTypes.DRUG_ALERT));
userInfo.Add((NSString)Constants.PushNotificationInfoKeys.NOTIFICATION_IDENTIFIER, (NSString)alert.Id);

//Pass this data to the function that creates a local notification

alarmService.CreateAlarm(alarmTime, string.Format(..., userInfo);
```

**The Create Alarm Function**

```
public Result<UILocalNotification> CreateAlarm(DateTime alertTime, string alertBody, string alertAction, NSMutableDictionary userInfo)
    {
        try
        {
           //Code truncated for clarity

            // create the notification
            var notification = new UILocalNotification();


            //Set the metadata for the alert
            notification.UserInfo = userInfo;


            // schedule it
                UIApplication.SharedApplication.ScheduleLocalNotification(notification);


            return Result<UILocalNotification>.Success(notification);


        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return Result<UILocalNotification>.Failure(ex.Message);
        }

    }
```

How I retrieve the data in the `ReceivedLocalNotification`

```
 if (notification.UserInfo.ContainsKey(new NSString(Constants.PushNotificationInfoKeys.IS_RESPONSE_TO_SNOOZE)))
            {
              // Do something here
            }
```

How I retrieve the data in iOS 10:

```
public class UserNotificationCenterDelegate : UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate
{

     public override void DidReceiveNotificationResponse(UNUserNotificationCenter center, UNNotificationResponse response, Action completionHandler)
    {
        try
        {
          NSString[] keys = { new NSString(Constants.PushNotificationInfoKeys.NOTIFICATION_TYPE) };

           var mystring = new NSString(Constants.PushNotificationInfoKeys.NOTIFICATION_TYPE);

            var alertId = response.Notification.GetDictionaryOfValuesFromKeys(keys).ValueForKey(mystring);  //App crashes on this line

        }catch (Exception ex)
        {

            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message + ex.StackTrace);
        }

}
```

How can I access the `UserInfo` property in iOS 10? Any ideas?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a little research, I learnt that you can access the UserInfo property from the response object inside the `DidReceiveNotificationResponse` function like this:

```
var userInfo = response.Notification.Request.Content.UserInfo;

            if (userInfo != null)
            {
                var value = userInfo.ValueForKey(mystring);

                if (userInfo.ContainsKey(new NSString(Constants.PushNotificationInfoKeys. NOTIFICATION_TYPE)))
                {
                    //Do something here
                }
                Console.WriteLine("Value :" + value);

            }
```